# Radio button CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to use css to replace all my radio buttons the same way. Is it possible to use css to just make these radio buttons work no matter where the location of the input is? I dont want to to have to adjust for rows or anything. Just by grabbing the radio button and cssing it the way i have in the example below.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.radio {
  border: 1px solid #b3b4b4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
}
.row:hover .radio {
  border: 2px solid #218996;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio {
  background-color: #218996;
  border: 2px solid #218996;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio::before {
  content: "✓ ";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:
}
.row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.row label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row > label:last-child {
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form name="titleTypes" id="titleTypes" method="post" action="process.cfm">
  <div>
    <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
    <label for="rgroup" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="one" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MV/titleTypeMV.cfm" />
    <label for="one" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="one">MOTOR VEHICLE / TRAVEL TRAILER TITLE</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="two" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MH/mobileHome.cfm" />
    <label for="two" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="two">MOBILE HOME</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="three" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="BOAT/boat.cfm" />
    <label for="three" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="three">VESSEL</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <input id="four" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="DUPL/duplicate.cfm" />
    <label for="four" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="four">DUPLICATE</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn"><i></i>Next</button>
  </div>
```

I want the input radio to be able to just work exactly as these radio buttons whether there on a table or any where just by calling the class. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you have an example of what you want so we can show you how to do it?

Comment: i posted the css above as my example of what i want

Comment: I want the radio button to function like above in my example but work any where. If you try to use the above in a table it breaks the radio button. Trying to see how i can do universal

Comment: @DavidBrierton check out my answer and let me know if that's what you meant or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per our conversation in the comments, I slightly modified your CSS to work outside of the rows they were designed for. Mainly, I added a `clear: both;` to `.radio` to put each input on a new line, and added `float: left;` to both labels so they keep in line.

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.radio {
  border: 1px solid #b3b4b4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px -20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio {
  background-color: #218996;
  border-color: #218996;
}
input[type='radio']:active + .radio,
input[type='radio']:focus + .radio {
  border-color: lightblue;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio::before {
  content: "✓ ";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
label {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="radio" name="rgroup" tabindex='1' />
<label for="one" class='radio'></label>
<label for="one">Button 1</label>

<input id="two" type="radio" name="rgroup" tabindex='2' />
<label for="two" class='radio'></label>
<label for="two">Button 2</label>
```

Comment: When you click in yours now its not showing the checkmark. Also when i tab through them how come space bar does not select it?

Comment: @DavidBrierton Refresh - I accidentally made a typo in the background-color. Enter button will fill a radio button, but not spacebar.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: yes i saw that. can you explain when you try to tab through them why you can not select them with the spacebar?

Comment: @DavidBrierton Yes - you can't use spacebar like normally because the actual radio buttons (`<input type="radio" />`) are hidden via CSS (`display: none`) to show the graphical "radio buttons" that your CSS created. The browser does not treat the styled labels the same as input buttons with keyboard controls.

Comment: is there a way to select them? or does it just show and you cant ever select? hahaha so it defeats the tabbing process?

Comment: or can you use the input and not do display none just adjust the css it already has so the functionality of the space bar could still work?

Comment: just trying to see whats possible and whats not since im very new to coding

Comment: @DavidBrierton It's a bit hacky, but I modified my example to hide the actual radio button via `opacity: 0`, which makes it invisible but keeps it clickable/functional. Then I moved the `taborder` attribute to the `input` so the `label`s no longer get highlighted. Then I added CSS to style the graphical fake radio buttons as if they were being highlighted when the actual radio buttons have focus, and added negative margin-left to the graphical radio button to appear where the real button is. Note that the keyboard arrow keys normally let you change between radio buttons (not just spacebar).

Answer (score 0):

When you say do it by classes, do you mean you want to be able to toggle from one state to another state without JS/jQ? Here's a demo I did in CSS, which shows how to hook into a `radio` or ``` checkbox``:checked ``` state.

Added OP's example and fixed the jerky motion when hovered over. This side-effect occurs when a state has more padding, margins, font-size, borders, etc. than it's counterpart. For example, take Snippet 2 as an example.

- When hovered over the radio buttons and row would jerk around which is very irritating and distracting. In this case, there were several rulesets that had a border of 1px, while others had 2px. All you have to do is make sure all borders have the same width.
- Added inset `box-shadow` to each radio to give them some depth on hover.
- Added `box-shadow` to each row in order to define them a little.
- Added animated borders to each row as well.

**SNIPPET 1**

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #111;
  color: #DDD;
  font: 400 16px/1.4'Verdana';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
  outline: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
}
fieldset {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: 3px double #FF8;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 19em;
}
legend {
  font: small-caps 700 1.5rem/2"Palatino Linotype";
  color: #FD1;
}
/* CheX */

#chex input.chkrad {
  display: none;
}
#chex input.chkrad + label {
  color: #DDD;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#chex input.chkrad + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: -1px 15px 0 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#chex input + label span {
  background: #555;
  line-height: 100%;
}
input.X:checked + label span {
  padding: -3px 10px 3px;
}
input.X:checked + label span:before {
  content: 'X';
  color: #F00;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/* RadZ */

#radz input.chkrad {
  display: none;
}
#radz input.chkrad + label {
  color: #EEE;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#radz input.chkrad + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -1px 15px 0 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#radz input + label span {
  background: #555;
  line-height: 100%;
}
input.A:checked + label span {
  padding: -5px 15px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input.A:checked + label span:before {
  content: '';
  color: #e3e;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
}
input.B:checked + label span {
  padding: -5px 15px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input.B:checked + label span:before {
  content: '';
  color: #f99;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  text-align: left;
}
input.C:checked + label span {
  padding: -2px 15px 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input.C:checked + label span:before {
  content: '';
  color: #3ef;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: .75;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
input.D:checked + label span {
  padding: -5px 15px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input.D:checked + label span:before {
  content: '';
  color: #eee;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: .75;
}
input.fade + label span,
input.fade:checked + label span {
  -webkit-transition: background 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.7s linear;
  transition: background 0.7s linear;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="chex" name="chex">
  <legend><span class="red">X</span> Marks the Checkbox</legend>
  <input type='checkbox' name='chk3' id="chk3" class="chkrad X fade" value='x' />
  <label for="chk3"><span></span>Red "X" mark</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="radz" name="radz">
  <legend>Shore Leave</legend>
  <input type='radio' name='rad' id="rad1" class="chkrad A fade" value='1' />
  <label for="rad1"><span></span>Brawl</label>
  <br/>
  <input type='radio' name='rad' id="rad2" class="chkrad B fade" value='2' />
  <label for="rad2"><span></span>Women</label>
  <br/>
  <input type='radio' name='rad' id="rad3" class="chkrad C fade" value='3' />
  <label for="rad3"><span></span>Drink</label>
  <br/>
  <input type='radio' name='rad' id="rad4" class="chkrad D fade" value='4' />
  <label for="rad4"><span></span>All of the above, matey!</label>
  <br/>
</fieldset>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.radio {
  border: 2px solid #b3b4b4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
}
.row:hover .radio {
  border: 2px solid #218996;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #218996;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio {
  background-color: #218996;
  border: 2px solid #218996;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + .radio::before {
  content: "✓ ";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.row {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 128, 192, .3);
}
.row label {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row > label:last-child {
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-u {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row.bdr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1.5px;
}
.row.bdr::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0s ease, background .5s ease;
}
.row.bdr::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: rgba(51, 112, 44, .4);
  transition: width .5s ease;
}
.row.bdr:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(100, 177, 255, .4);
  transition: width .5s ease;
}
.row.bdr:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0s ease;
}
```

```html
<form name="titleTypes" id="titleTypes" method="post" action="process.cfm">
  <div>
    <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
    <label for="rgroup" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row bdr'>
    <input id="one" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MV/titleTypeMV.cfm" />
    <label for="one" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="one">Motor Vehicle / Travel Trailer Title</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row bdr'>
    <input id="two" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="MH/mobileHome.cfm" />
    <label for="two" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="two">Moble Home</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row bdr'>
    <input id="three" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="BOAT/boat.cfm" />
    <label for="three" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="three">Vessel</label>
  </div>

  <div class='row bdr'>
    <input id="four" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="DUPL/duplicate.cfm" />
    <label for="four" class='radio' tabindex='1'></label>
    <label for="four">Duplicate</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn"><i></i>Next</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: This CSS technique was already being implemented in the OP's example.

Comment: At the time I arrived a minute earlier than you, the OP's post was incomplete, *: Yes, it's possible. Do you have an example of what you want so we can show you how to do it?* –  @JonUleis 1 hour ago. "i posted the css above as my example of what i want "` I added an improved version of OP's example, knowing only that he wanted some vague dribble about being *universal*